# find doesn't return expected files

Tags: find, filenames

I'm doing a search for files that contain ".anki" in their file name.

```
root@t500:/home/some1# find / -name .anki
/home/some1/.anki
```

But there are other files in my home folder that contain .anki:

```
all-feb-18-2013.anki
all-mar-10-2013.anki
all-oct-06-2012.anki
```

Why don't those appear with my search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find`'s `-name` predicate accepts [shell-like globbing](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) patterns. These patterns are anchored to the starts and ends of lines. Try this instead:

```
find / -name '*.anki'
```

The `*` is a wildcard. It will match zero or more characters. Without it, `find` will search for files named `.anki`. Be sure to quote the `*`. If you don't, the shell will expand it.

You can also use regular expressions with some variants of find.

```
find / -regex '.*\.anki'
```

See the [`find(1)`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) manpage for more information.

Comment: Why doesn't it work with what I used.. is it looking for exact matches only in my version?

Comment: @some1: Your version is looking for exact matches. I've updated my question a bit.